# Is there a tool to generate SyntaxFactory-Statements from C# source code for code generation in source generators

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, csharp-source-generator

I am generating (C#) code in a .net source generator project.

The structure of the code is generated using the `SyntaxFactory`-Methods/object model (from `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`).

It is tedious (and for some statements, complicated, as the documentation if fairly thin) to create the correct sequence of SyntaxFactory-calls to emit the correct logic. It would be easier to write boilerplate C# Code, and have some sort of tool which parses the C# code and generates the equivalent syntax tree for the correct sequence of SyntaxFactory-calls for this code.

I looked at some projects using source generators on github (most notably, Orleans from Microsoft), but haven't found such helpers yet.

Does such a tool exist? Can someone please point me to it?

The best I could come up with yet ist a tool which does `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText()`, and then I look in the debugger at the tree or use a simple visitor over the tree.

Thanks

Comment: You could perhaps look at the source code of https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ ?

Comment: thx, perfect! I knew I missed something